# ESlint errors after a fresh install of Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint

I created a nuxtjs project using yarn with the command

```
yarn create nuxt-app <project-name>
```

I run the command

```
yarn dev
```

Everything is fine, but when I create a new file to test the nuxtjs router I get this error

```
Demo page
ERROR in 
C:\Users\thienkd\Desktop\CMS-Temp\pages\demo\index.vue
   1:11  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   2:10  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   3:27  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   4:11  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   5:12  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   6:1   error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   7:9   error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
   8:1   error  Replace `····export·default·{␍⏎␍⏎····}␍` with `export·default·{}`  prettier/prettier
  11:10  error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
  12:1   error  Delete `␍`                                                         prettier/prettier
  13:15  error  Replace `␍⏎␍⏎</style>␍` with `</style>`                            prettier/prettier

✖ 11 problems (11 errors, 0 warnings)
  11 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
ERROR in 
pages/demo/index.vue
 14:2  ×  Unexpected empty source   no-empty-source
```

And my pages directory just contains:

```
pages
    |_index.vue
    |_demo
          |_index.vue
```

Have you had a similar situation like me? Can you help me handle this problem?

Comment: can you post your index.vue as well?

Comment: @kusiaga I found an error. it is due to eslint. thanks

Answer (score 0):

During the install, you probably chose to use [ESlint](https://eslint.org/) (and maybe [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) too) when you installed your project, those errors are coming from it. Those are essentially more of "warnings" to prevent you from making mistakes down the road.

You can either lint it with `yarn lint` (check your `package.json`) or install a plugin in your code editor to make it format for you on save. If you're using VScode, [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) is the package for it.